How to connect a open vSwitch interface to physical interface of another host?
I want to connect a switch interface to physical interface of another host. I am using Open vSwitch and ryu controller. I have one physical interface i.e., enp4s2 (IP address = 192.168.10.2/24) and below is the code I have used to
-create mininet,
-add hosts, switches and controlles
-create Links between switch and host
-connected switch to external host interface.
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Controller, OVSKernelSwitch, RemoteController
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.link import Intf, TCLink
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info

from mininet.topo import Topo

class MyTopo(Topo):
    "Simple topology example."

    def build( self ):
        "Create custom topo."

        # Add hosts and switches
        '*** Add switches\n'
        s1 = self.addSwitch('s1', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
        info("**type s1 --> ", type(s1), "\n")

        '*** Add hosts\n'
        h1 = self.addHost('h1')
        info("**type h1 --> ", type(h1), "\n")
       
        # Add links
        '*** Add links\n'
        self.addLink(h1, s1)
   
def configure_mininet_host(net):
    # Configure Mininet host IP address
    h1 = net.get('h1')
    h1.setIP('192.168.10.5/24')
   
def main():
    setLogLevel('info')
   
    # Create the network topology
    topo = MyTopo()
   
    # Initialize Mininet with the custom topology and no default controller
    net = Mininet(topo=topo, link=TCLink, switch=OVSKernelSwitch, controller=None)
   
    # Add ryu controller
    net.addController(name='ryu', controller=RemoteController, ip='127.0.0.1', port=6633)
   
    # Start the network
    net.start()
   
    # Connect the Mininet switch to the external host's interface
    s1_node = net.getNodeByName("s1")
    Intf("enp4s2", node=s1_node)
   
    # Configure Mininet host IP address
    configure_mininet_host(net)
   
    # Start the CLI
    CLI(net)
   
    # Stop the network
    net.stop() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

The interface enp4s2 is connected to another host physical interface via ethernet cable(IP address = 192.168.10.1/24) and I want to communicate with that host using the mininet.
But I am unable to
-ping between hosts,
-ping between host and switch
When I am trying to use following command
mininet> pingall

*** Ping: testing ping rechability
h1 ->
*** Warning: No packets sent
